# Android: Emulator control is disabled in the DDMS perspective

Tags: android, eclipse, ddms

I'm now facing a problem with Eclipse on Ubuntu. My device is connected, list by "adb devices" command and I can see the list of processes running in the Devices view. But all controls in the Emulator Control are disabled.

Does anyone know what may be the reason for this?

Thanks

Comment: And same is seen while testing the app on emulator

Answer (score 25, accepted):

First, make sure that the device is selected in the Devices view. You cannot use Emulator Control unless the device or emulator is selected.

If that does not help, close Eclipse, and try running DDMS outside of Eclipse -- there's a `ddms` shell script in the `tools/` directory of wherever you installed the Android SDK.

If that does not help, run `adb kill-server`, followed by `adb start-server`, where `adb` should be in your `platform-tools/` directory of your SDK installation. Then, try DDMS again.

If that does not help, reboot, then try DDMS again.

Comment: Mark, thanks for your answer. Although I have no idea what helped me (Emulator control is fine now), I'm going to accept this answer

Comment: when I made sure that the device was selected , all thinks became well :-) , thanks @CommonWare

Comment: as of jellybean ddms is deprecated. Run "./monitor" from the same directory.

Comment: ah..also make sure your device is an emulator and not a physical usb device. it appears you can't use ddms emulator control on a usb device so the controls are disabled.

Comment: didn't worked for me. i tried to restart Eclipse, restart emulator and ddms from outside. Didn't helped.

Answer (score 3):

i found this with try and error .. it worked ..
As the new emulator got a side bar with icons .. the last icon down this list (the hamburger icon) click it .. then u will have the location latitude and longitude available to send to device

Answer (score 2):

After unplugging USB connection from real device  Emulator Control start  work  properly with Virtual devices

Answer (score 2):

You can't send locations to actual devices, only emulators. You can mock your devices location however, in your code.

http://developer.android.com/training/location/location-testing.html