# Why Android Device Monitor doesn't work?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-device-monitor

I don't know why it doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: Can you please include a bit more context?  What device are you trying monitor?  What is the status of "adb devices" etc....

Comment: I am trying to use Emulator Control and it doesn't work ...

Comment: Really could use more information in your question.  Also possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5059658/android-emulator-control-is-disabled-in-the-ddms-perspective

Comment: One good tip for posting questions is that if you find yourself about to use the phrase `it doesn't work`, either in questions or clarifying comments, stop! Try not to use the phrase at all, since it is surprisingly nondescript. Instead, explain what you did, what you expected to happen, and what actually happened, and be as detailed as you can.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any emulators installed? Are you tying to use USB connection to a real device? I once had issue detecting my Android phone. I resolved it by switching the USB connection option to "Camera" as opposed to "Media Device".