# android - change gps coords on device emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-gps

I am trying to make a simple GPS app so I want to check it on my device emulator.

So, I enable the ADB integration in android studio through Tools>android>enable ADB integration, then I open the device monitor, and then from there I open an emulator from window>Android Virtual Device Manager.

I then press the green arrow to run my app, it launches on the emulator, but from some reason, in the device monitor emulator, all the options are disabled as follows on this picture:

[all options are disabled](https://i.imgsafe.org/03738ed817.gif)

any ideas what to do so I can change the coords?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5059997/2199949) about debugging your greyed out Location Controls in AVD Manager. Even though its pre Android Studio, the suggested `tools/` folder in the SDK folder still applies. (Here's [Tips on finding SDK location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25176594/android-sdk-location) if needed.)

You might also try [these methods](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html#MockData) from the Android API Guides. The third method near the bottom of the page, which uses telnet in terminal, is my favorite.